# cy.exec() doesn't work with new Cypress version 12.16.0

Tags: node.js, cypress

`cy.exec()` is not working in 12.16.0 version of cypress.

It is throwing the following error:

[image: Error message]

But the same code is working on lower version of cypress.

I upgrade my cypress version to latest one and this error occurs . Later I tried with lower version and the same code works.

Comment: Can you double check your versions? There was a similar issue (with the same error message) occurring in Cypress 12.15.0 that was fixed in 12.16.0 -> https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/27099 and https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#12-16-0

Answer (score 3):

The screenshot you posted shows that you are using an incorrect syntax.

The 2nd and 3rd parameters should be combined into one `options` object

From the docs,

[image]

Use this syntax instead:

```js
cy.exec('node index.js', {failOnNonZeroExit:false, timeout:20_000})
```

If your invalid syntax works in older Cypress versions, then congratulation you found a bug in the older versions.

But I suspect that they were just ignoring the superfluous 3rd parameter, and you were not getting the timeout you expected.